# "Check All" function when using Ryan Fait's "Custom Form Elements"

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I've made a simple form using Ryan Fait's Custom Form Elements. Now I am trying to implement a "Check All"/"Uncheck All" function.

What I have mostly works, except that the user has to click the buttons twice to get the desired result. I have a feeling that I need to call this function from inside the Custom Form Elements script, but I don't know how.

I'm using JQuery, Custom Form Elements (http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/custom-form-elements.js), and this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function cboxToggle(group, action) {
for( var i=0, len = group.length; i < len; i++) {
group[i].checked = action;
}
}

</script>
```

My HTML:

```
<form name="myname" action="checkboxes.asp" method="post">
<input type = "button" value = " CHECK ALL" onclick = "cboxToggle(check_list, !this.checked)"><br>
<input type = "button" value = " UNCHECK ALL" onclick = "cboxToggle(check_list, this.checked)"><br>

<p><input type="checkbox" name="check_list" value="1" class="styled" />Option 1 </p> 
<p><input type="checkbox" name="check_list" value="2" class="styled" />Option 2 </p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="check_list" value="3" class="styled" />Option 3 </p>
</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery then why not use it to its full potential? Which also means, no inline code... Add an id to your buttons first. Then make sure you're using groups properly, so instead of `group` you do `group[]`. Then use this code and it should work:

```
var ckToggle = function (group, action) {
  $('[name="'+ group +'"]').prop('checked', action)
}

$('#buttonAll').click(function(){ ckToggle('check_list[]', true) })
$('#buttonNone').click(function(){ ckToggle('check_list[]', false) })
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, elclanrs! I must be missing something. I gave each of the buttons the ids and replaced my JS with yours. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Got it working here http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/MXVne/. I missed a quote so maybe that's why it wasn't working, check the code again.

Comment: It looking great in your jsfiddle, but for some reason it's not working on my server. Feeling stupid, I'm sure it's something obvious. See my test page here: http://devel.isetgroup.com/js-playground/test.html

Comment: Yes - that's what was missing. Thanks. Works great with default form elements, but I still have the same problem with the custom form elements. I have to click the buttons twice to get them to work.

Comment: I enhanced my test example to include the Custom Form Elements.js: http://devel.isetgroup.com/js-playground/test.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following URL

[Uncheck checkbox in custom form elements](http://www.apnacode.com/javascript/how-to-uncheck-checkbox-in-custom-form-elements-using-javascript/)