# Jquery check all using toggle method

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle

How with jquery can I make a check all uncheck all selection I have it so I can select each individual one, but with over 20 checkbox's I need to select all or deselect all

```
<input type="checkbox" name="filters" rel="2" checked="checked" /> name
 &emsp; <input type="checkbox" name="filters" rel="3" checked="checked" />tname
&emsp;<input type="checkbox" name="filters" rel="4" checked="checked" />lname
```

JQUERY

```
$(function(){
    $(':checkbox').on('change', function(){
        $('td').filter(':nth-child(' + $(this).attr('rel') + ')').toggle();
        $('th').filter(':nth-child(' + $(this).attr('rel') + ')').toggle();
    });
})
```

Each one will hide a field at this time but would be nice for a check all checkbutton.

Thanks

Comment: Check my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352287/check-all-function-when-using-ryan-faits-custom-form-elements/11352400#11352400), posted a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) function (jQuery v1.6+):

To check all:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true);
```

To uncheck all:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
```

To check if an input is checked, you can use `if (this.checked)`

Comment: Zee, Using this allows me to check and uncheck all the checkboxes, but doesn't toggle the fields in my table. each check box will hide a table row. Is there a way to incorporate a check all into this?

Comment: Instead of using `toggle` use `if (this.checked)` in your `change` event.